# I am getting an error - (array() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given) while creating an array in python 3.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.7

```
"""
Array Operations
"""


def array():
    import array as arr
    my_array = arr.array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4])
    print(str(my_array))


array()
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code as it works inside another class function.

Comment: The code you've posted does not reproduce the error you are describing.

Comment: Is it possible that you have created a file called `array.py`? That could cause a problem similar to what you describe.

Comment: @khelwood yes, this could be the problem, module name might be `array.py`, I will check.

Comment: @khelwood Error fixed by renaming the module, it was conflicting with the array module I was importing. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a file called `array.py`, when you write

```
import array
```

you're actually importing your file `array.py` instead of the standard module `array`. If you rename your `array.py` file something else, you'll avoid this problem.